# How to utilise Entity Framework with a database hierarchy from API data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, api, restsharp

I might not have worded this question in the correct format as it's difficult to explain what the problem is. From the research I've gathered I think database hierarchy is something that I'm trying to utilize when using Entity Framework to create a database, I'll try to explain my problem in the best way possible.

Firstly, I'm running a Visual Studio 2019 project with a console application. This is my Program.cs file which is currently using a get request from an API URL with RESTSHARP then performing deserialization.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getAPIData()
        } 

    public static void getAPIData()
            {
                var client = new RestClient(URL);
                var request = new RestRequest();
                var response = client.Execute(request);
    
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string rawResponse = response.Content;
                    Requests.Rootobject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Requests.Rootobject>(rawResponse);
                }
            }
```

As you can see above, the raw data that's gathered from the URL (my API) is converted to a JSON format. And when I debug the code, it stores the code perfectly into the Requests DTO, as I'll show below.

```
public class Requests
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Operation operation { get; set; }
        }

        public class Operation
        {
            public Result result { get; set; }
            public Detail[] details { get; set; }
        }

        public class Result
        {
            public string message { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
        }

        public class Detail
        {
            public string requester { get; set; }
            public string workorderid { get; set; }
            public string accountname { get; set; }
         }
    }
```

The recently converted API data is now stored in this class in this correct format. Which is what's necessary for the API itself since it comes in numerous classes. This object now holds all the relevant data I need, now I can utilize the entity framework to generate an appropriate table that will hold this into an SQL server.

Here is the Entity Framework class.

```
 public class TransitionContext : DbContext
    {
        private const string connectionString = @"(connection string here)";

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }

        public DbSet<Requests> Requesting { get; set; }
    }
```

Currently, when I run the package manager console commands to build a migration and setup a connection to the server, it works fine (Obviously I've not included my real connection string for privacy reasons). However, when I use the "Update-Database" command from the  DbSet which is my DTO for the API data. The only key that is displayed is an ID, nothing else.

[SQL requests table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf4aI.png)

All that's generated here is an Id key from the Requests Dto. Now, on the API itself, there is no ID key, I added it in there because Entity Framework said I had to have an ID key and was displaying errors until I made one. But now that's all it's generating when I "Update-Database".

The reason why I showed as much data as I have done, is because the process is simply exporting the converted JSON data (a recently gathered API) into an SQL table. Or tables so that it supports a hierarchy, anything that will map correctly from the DTO to the database. But as of right now, my only issue with the project is that only an ID is being generated.

So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here or how to get this working as I intend it to work. Apologies for the really long explanation, I tried to condense it as much as I could, any help would be appreciated and any questions I'm free to answer, thank you!

Comment: You're confusing nested classes with properties.

Comment: I don't follow? @GertArnold

Comment: `Requests` only has `Id` as property. That property is all you can store now, since `Request` is the only mapped class.. `Rootobject` etc. are just classes, not properties, and these classes aren't mapped in EF.

Comment: Okay thank you @GertArnold I think I've misunderstood how EF operates and thought it was more straight forward, I appreciate your response.